# fragmentTransaction.replace().commit() calls onCreate of parent Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a parent activity that stores several fragments, in the activity's onCreate I launch the first fragment

```
FatherFragment fatherFragment = new FatherFragment ();
RegisterActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager (). BeginTransaction ().add (R.id.fragmentContainer, parentFragment, "RegisterParentFragment").commit ();
```

In the application the fragment is displayed correctly, but this fragment has a button that calls another fragment to replace it

```
MapsFragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("idPersona", idPersona);
mapsFragment.setArguments (bundle);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mapsFragment, "mapaFragment")
                        .commit();
```

The problem resides in that, when making the fragment change (which if it is done) the onCreate method of the parent activity is launched again and shows me the first fragment over of the fragment that has just changed.

I have to assume that it is the view that is running again, but I would like to know if someone could help me find the solution to this problem.

I add that it is a series of steps between fragments and every time I switch, the same problem reappears.

Greetings and thanks for your time. Sorry for bad english.

Adding onClick method.

```
btnSgtPadre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        guardarPersona(objPersona);
        MapsFragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("idPersona", idPersona);
        mapsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mapsFragment,"mapaFragment")
                .commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share the code of your click method?

Comment: @NehaK added method.

Comment: I think the app is crashing on this method.if the app crahses, the whole app relaunch again. Try to see log if there is any "FATAL" message

Comment: No FATAL messages in debug/log/run

Comment: what's inside guardarPersona?

Comment: encapsulation of data, only write in firebase

Comment: try my answer, hope it will help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

in your Activity create method, which will add this fragment :

```
public void switchToSecondFragment(Object idPersona){

 MapsFragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("idPersona", idPersona);
        mapsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mapsFragment,"mapaFragment")
                .commit();
}
```

And call it like this :

```
btnSgtPadre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        guardarPersona(objPersona);
        ((<YourActivityName>) getActivity()).switchToSecondFragment(idPersona); 

    }
});
```

Most likely reason could be : App is restarting due to crash. Sometimes we don't get logs as well if app restarts.. try this and let me know.

**Crash reason :**

replace() method finds the ID inside your current fragment's layout, as you are passing "R.id.fragmentContainer", and your current fragment doesn't contain this "id", so you might me getting crash that this doesn't contain this id called "R.id.fragmentContainer". So you will have to add this fragment by writing method inside Activity itself.

**If you want to confirm , add TryCatch :**

```
try{




 MapsFragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("idPersona", idPersona);
        mapsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mapsFragment,"mapaFragment")
                .commit();




}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Tank you!. In my case have 3 or 4 fragments, so i have to send the fragment to activity method.

Comment: I have same issue again... can you help me pls? im student and i have my first job :( sorry for bad english

Comment: what issue you are getting?